# Is there a way to remove duplicate rows with a specific condition within Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, duplicates

I have a dataframe (df) that contains some overlapping time rows. I would like to delete the row with the  longer duration, keeping the row with the shorter duration from the same ID. (to reduce overlapping)

```
    starttime                  endtime                      ID      Diff

    1/7/2020 2:32:15 PM        1/7/2020 2:32:16 PM          A       1 sec
    1/8/2020 2:33:20 PM        1/8/2020 2:33:22 PM          B       2 sec
    1/9/2020 5:35:00 AM        1/9/2020 5:35:25 AM          C       25 sec
    1/9/2020 5:35:05 AM        1/9/2020 5:35:25 AM          C       20 sec
```

I would like the following outcome:

```
    starttime                  endtime                      ID      Diff

    1/7/2020 2:32:15 PM        1/7/2020 2:32:16 PM          A       1 sec
    1/8/2020 2:33:20 PM        1/8/2020 2:33:22 PM          B       2 sec
    1/9/2020 5:35:05 AM        1/9/2020 5:35:25 AM          C       20 sec
```

Notice that the first row from Group C is removed because the time duration was longer than the first row from Group C.

This is my code:

```
        import numpy as np
        import pandas as pd

        subset = df[df['diff'] >=  )
        df.drop(subset, inplace = True)
```

My dilemma is that I do not know how to correctly write the proper code to delete the longer duration row. (keeping the row with the shorter duration) I have researched this and have come up with the above code. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check df.drop_duplicates() in Pandas. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Answer (score 3):

Use `sort_values` then `drop_duplicates`:

```
df.sort_values(['ID', 'Diff']).drop_duplicates(subset=['ID'])
```

Output:

```
             starttime              endtime ID  Diff
0  1/7/2020 2:32:15 PM  1/7/2020 2:32:16 PM  A     1
1  1/8/2020 2:33:20 PM  1/8/2020 2:33:22 PM  B     2
3  1/9/2020 5:35:05 AM  1/9/2020 5:35:25 AM  C    20
```

Comment: ok let me try, Is this essentially removing the row with the longer duration?

Comment: Yes, within the `ID` group. I took the liberty of having `Diff` column `int`, but if you need to convert (i.e. remove `sec`), do let me know

Comment: Ok I will try this first thing in the morning please to see if this works for me

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the duration is all in `sec`, you can:

Extract the duration as an integer and sort it:

```py
df['duration'] = df['Diff'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(float)
df = df.sort_values('duration')
```

Then remove duplications

```py
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['starttime','endtime','ID'], keep='first')
```

Comment: ok I will try. Is this removing the row with the longer duration?

Comment: It is, but it depends on the format of `'Diff'` column. If it is a `datetime` column, prob @Chris answer will address it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `groupby`:

```
df['Diff'] = df['Diff'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(float)
print(df.loc[df.groupby('ID')['Diff'].idxmin()])
```

I first only extract numeric values from each string in the `Diff` column, then I convert it to a `float`, then I group by the `ID` column and get the index with the minimum value of each group, then I use `loc` to extract those indexes.

Comment: Ok thank you I will try in the morning. Can you explain what the code is doing please? I understand some, but not all. I will try this tomorrow morning

Comment: @anky_91 check now

Comment: it is saying invalid syntax error:  File "<ipython-input-19-91a47f00be6a>", line 2
    print(df.loc[df.groupby('ID')['Diff'].idxmin())])

Comment: @TanishaHudson Try now